# Initialize the matrix with 255 when using openCV copyTo function?

Tags: opencv

When I use openCV 
    void Mat::copyTo(OutputArray m, InputArray mask)
function,  newly allocated matrix is initialized with all zeros before copying the data. Is there any way to initialize with 255 instead of zeros ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to allocate the output matrix before copying data to it. You can create a matrix initialized with a constant as follows `Mat A(3,3,CV_32F, Scalar(255))`. Alternatively, if you have a pre-declared matrix `A`, you can re-allocate it with `A.create(3,3,CV_32F)`, and then initialize it with a constant using `A = Scalar(255)`.

So in your case you can do the following:

```
// Create output matrix initialized with a constant
Mat output(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,255,255)); 

// Copy your `input` matrix into `output` through your `mask`
input.copyTo(output, mask);
```

Answer (score 7):

See OpenCV Doc about [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html)

You can create Mat with contant like

**Three channel**

```
   Mat M(cols,rows, CV_8UC3, Scalar::all(255));
```

**Single channel**

```
  Mat M(cols,rows, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));
```